# How to filter rows if index length not same in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter rows of one pandas dataframe (df_2) if values in df_1 are greater than or equal too.

df_1 looks like this:

```
created_date    compare_date
2/10/18         2/11/18
```

df_2 looks like this:

```
id   compare_date
12   2/10/18
13   2/11/18
14   2/9/18
```

I need do the following comparison: df_1['compare_date']>= df_2['compare_date'] and df_2 in turn should look like this:

```
id    compare_date
13    2/11/18
```

My code so far:

```
df_1['Benchmark_Date'] >= df_2['Updated_Date']
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
```

Comment: Your example is totally confused.  Please go through it step by step and make it clear and correct and consistent.

Comment: made some edits..hopefully clarifies everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `df_1` has exactly one row, you should compare its single value against the entire series in `df_2`:

```
df_1['compare_date'].iloc[0] >= df_2['compare_date']
```

`iloc[0]` takes the first (and in this case only) row.

The above will return a boolean series; if you want to extract the matched rows, do this:

```
df_2[df_1['compare_date'].iloc[0] >= df_2['compare_date']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am running the second line of code, but it is returning df_2 as is. I checked the dtypes in both df's and all dates columns are 'object'.  Do you think I should convert the date columns from object to date?

Comment: @RustyShackleford: Well of course that's true, because for your example data it is true.  Look at the data.  The code is working, you just need to decide why your expected outcome differs from what you asked for.

Comment: it worked! something wrong with how excel was storing the dates.